# How to export a rasterio window to an image without geo-reference information?

Tags: python, image-processing, gis, raster, rasterio

I would like to export a `rasterio` window to an image.

```py
import rasterio

def export_window(w, path):
    number_of_bands, height, width = w.shape

    profile = {
        "driver": "JPEG",
        "count": number_of_bands,
        "height": height,
        "width": width,
        'dtype': 'uint8'
    }
    with rasterio.open(path, 'w', **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(w)
```

Unfortunately, because I am not specifying a `transform` key in the `profile` above, I get the following warning:

```py
>>> raster = rasterio.open("/tmp/geo.tif")
>>> w = raster.read(window=rasterio.windows.Window(0, 0, 500, 500))
>>> export_window(w, "/tmp/export.jpg")
```

> NotGeoreferencedWarning: Dataset has no geotransform set. The identity matrix may be returned.

Is there a way to export a non-georeferenced image from a `rasterio` window without getting warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the transform, if you set it to an identity, the warning goes away:

```
import rasterio

def export_window(w, path):
    number_of_bands, height, width = w.shape

    profile = {
        "driver": "JPEG",
        "count": number_of_bands,
        "height": height,
        "width": width,
        'dtype': 'uint8',
        'transform': rasterio.Affine(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    }
    with rasterio.open(path, 'w', **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(w)
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try this I get: ` NotGeoreferencedWarning: The given matrix is equal to Affine.identity or its flipped counterpart. GDAL may ignore this matrix and save no geotransform without raising an error. This behavior is somewhat driver-specific.`

Comment: GDAL is geographical software. Usually, for geographical images, a transform must be there because it would map the image on the earth surface. That's why it's throwing all these warnings. If you do not care about geolocation, you might as well ignore them.